# PHP unset POST element due to a condition

Tags: php, arrays, http-post, unset

I have a form where there are some conditional logic to be satisfied.
In doing so,  After sending the form and receiving the POST array,  I need to unset a specific member of the *POST*  array due to the fact that some conditions are not satisfied.
However,  when using the *unset* command for the POST array,  the element is not unset at all.
I think it is due to the fact that the POST was received and the only way to unset or modify the POST array is by sending again the form.
But this is not possible.
Please check what I'm doing:

```
1) Send the form.
2) Receives the POST array:
    Array ( [i_itm] => Z-TEST JEA [44-1] => 2 [26-3] => 39 [26-3-d] => 23 [35] => 6 .....) 

3) Need to unset array's member whose key is ['26-3-d'].  
  if (in_array($value, $array)) {  
      unset ($_POST['26-3-d']);
    }
```

This should delete the 26-3-d member of the array.  But not,  the member still resides and gets processed by my code.

How can I unset the member once the *POST* array is received?

Comment: Have you tried unset with quotes and/or brackets?  unset ($_POST["26-3-d"]);

Comment: Your conditions aren't met, since `if(conditions are met)` is invalid.